# Retrieving model class dynamically in CBV

Tags: django, django-views

What is the proper way to retrieve the model class dynamically in a CBV?

I realize I have to use `apps.get_model`, but not sure where to do that.

I would like to make my delete (and other) views more "DRY".

```
class DeleteParamView(generic.DeleteView):
    # The following does not work since kwargs cannot be accessed
    #model = apps.get_model('patients', 'param' + self.kwargs['param_name'])  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.apps import apps
        self.model = apps.get_model('persons', 'param' + self.kwargs['param_name'])
        super(DeleteParamView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately self.kwargs cannot be accessed yet; at least I get `'DeleteParamView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`

I also tried to override `def get_model()` but that does not exist as part of the CBV.

Comment: For reference, check out this resource on Django's Class Based Views: http://ccbv.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    Model = apps.get_model('persons', 'param' + self.kwargs['param_name'])
    return Model.objects.all()
```